# SOAP Handler Implementation breaks webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, handler

I have a very simple SOAP client that I created with the help of the wsimport utility against my own webservice. The client works perfectly fine as is, but breaks when I add a Handler to the mix. Below is my working client, which prints '1' to the console...

```
public class MyFirstSoapClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) {    

        SuperSimpleServiceService sib = new SuperSimpleServiceService();
        ServiceEndpointInterface sei = sib.getSuperSimpleServicePort();

        System.out.println(sei.return1());
    }
}
```

Now for the interesting part, here is the same client with the handler implementation followed by the output...

```
public class MyFirstSoapClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SuperSimpleServiceService sib = new SuperSimpleServiceService();
        sib.setHandlerResolver(new HandlerRegistration());
        ServiceEndpointInterface sei = sib.getSuperSimpleServicePort();

        System.out.println(sei.return1());

    }
}
```

**output**

```
MyHandler: getHeaders
MyHandler: handleMessage
MyHandler: close
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://interfaces.wsd.oce/}return1Response but found: {http://interfaces.wsd.oce/}return1
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.verifyTag(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.verifyTag(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.ResponseBuilder$DocLit.readResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.return1(Unknown Source)
    at oce.wsd.client.MyFirstSoapClient.main(MyFirstSoapClient.java:22)
```

Note that in the output, there are 3 lines printed before the exception, these are coming from my handler class, which proves that it is registered and working correctly. I realize that this is somewhat limited information, but I have no clue where to even look to fix this problem. Any ideas where to start? please let me know if any additional classes will help...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with a dummy SoapHandler implementation. (same call order with your log: getHeaders, handleMessage, close, Exception). 
Turns out my problem was returning false from handleMessage method. Documentation states: "Return true to continue processing."
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html

Comment: 2 days of pain and you make it go away, thank you very much !